# For all natural numbers $x$ and $y$, there is a natural number $z$ such that $x=y+z$ or $y=x+z$

Tags: arithmetic, peano-axioms

I am quite confussed because i can't proof the fallowing: $$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N},\; \exists z \in N: x=y+z \;\text{ or }\; y=x+z.$$ I am allowed to use induction and definition of addition. Thanks for your support.

Comment: What is your definition of addition? Think about the cases $x\leq y$ or $x>y$.

Comment: Let $P(k) = (\forall x,y \leqslant k)(\exists z \in \mathbb{N})(y = x+z \lor x = y+z)$.

Comment: Do you include 0 in your definition of "natural number"?

Answer (score 1):

By induction on $x$:

For $x=0$ we have to show $$\forall y\in\mathbb N,\exists z\in\mathbb N\colon 0=y+z\lor y=0+z$$
This is clearly fulfilled by letting $z=y$.

Now assume we have for seom $x\in\mathbb N$ that 
$$\forall y\in\mathbb N,\exists z\in\mathbb N\colon x=y+z\lor y=x+z$$
We want to show 
$$\forall y\in\mathbb N,\exists z\in\mathbb N\colon Sx=y+z\lor y=Sx+z$$
So let $y\in\mathbb N$ be arbitrary. Then there is $z\in\mathbb N$ such that $x=y+z\lor y=x+z$.
In the first case, we find $Sx=S(y+z)=y+Sz$.
In the second case, either $z=0$ and then $y=x$, hence $Sx=y+1$, or $z=Sw$ for some $w\in\mathbb N$ and hence $y=x+z=x+Sw=S(x+w)=Sx+w$.